# Can't start Cassandra 3.11.6 service after restart the ubuntu 16.04 machine

Tags: cassandra, nosql, datastax

I have Cassandra 3.11.6 in my ubuntu 16.04. Once I install Cassandra at use at fist time it is works fine. But I restart my machine then try to connect it shows error like this:

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

Also I check the service Cassandra status and it shows like this :

```
● cassandra.service - LSB: distributed storage system for structured data

   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/cassandra; bad; vendor preset: enabled)

   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2020-04-03 19:51:24 IST; 1h 8min ago

   Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

  Process: 1653 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/cassandra start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Why am I getting this error, and how to fix it?

Comment: What does the system.log say after running a `service cassandra start`?

Comment: No, its not get any latest updated.
last update is before my machine restart.

Comment: Ok, so go to your Cassandra directory, and run `bin/cassandra -f` and see what it tells you.

Comment: it show this:
[0.000s][warning][gc] -Xloggc is deprecated. Will use -Xlog:gc:/var/log/cassandra/gc.log instead.
intx ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 is outside the allowed range [ 0 ... 1 ]
Improperly specified VM option 'ThreadPriorityPolicy=42'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 is outside the allowed range
```

So this error is specific to the JVM, not to Cassandra.  Cassandra 3.11.6 runs on a max JVM (major) version of 1.8.  If you run a `java -version` and see a version listed of 1.9 or higher, then you'll need to install a 1.8 version of the JDK just for Cassandra.

As to why this error suddenly came about, I have no idea.  My guess is that the JDK was updated between the install and the reboot.

> But I also have OpenJDK 1.8, how do I set for Cassandra?

Set the `$JAVA_HOME` environment variable to your JDK 1.8 directory.  This variable is used by the `bin/cassandra` script, if present.

Comment: Yes, You are correct. I download the open JDK 11 before reboot. But I also have open JDK 1.8 how do I set for Cassandra.

Comment: @RamS Edit made.

Comment: But I want the JAVA_HOME environment variable as a to represent the JDK 11 directory for another purpose.
Now what I do?

Comment: @RamS ok, so set it in your service definition.